Trouble using JPA with TenantID column in Spring Boot
I'm trying to create a multi-tenancy system for my CRM system. Basically every company using the software has their own sets of tables(aside from the tenants table itself).
I would like to separate the data using a TenantID Column.
The flow would be like that
Sign in

User Signs in
gets JWT token

User adds new Meeting

User sends request
Controller receives request with JWT
Controller sends addMeeting to MeetingService
MeetingService extract uid from token
MeetingService fetches the corresponding tenant and tenantID
MeetingService sets the TenantID in a request scoped TenantContext bean
MeetingService fetches all Potentially conflicting Meetings (hopefully using the TenantID to find only meetings of the given tenant)
If no conflict remains, a new meeting is added with the proper tenant id set

There should also be a handful of endpoints and tables that don't use the tenantID at all
Here's what I have so far
import java.util.Map;
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
//This class is supposed to set the tenantContextString in JPA
public class TenantIdentifierResolver implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver<String>, HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    TenantContext tenantContext=null;



    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        if(tenantContext.getCurrentTenant()==null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("No tenant set");

        return tenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
    }

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put(AvailableSettings.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return false;
    }
}



@Component
@RequestScope
//The controller can set the appropriate TenantContext for each request
public class TenantContext  {
    @Getter @Setter
    private String currentTenant=null;
}

Here's my hibernate config
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.multiTenancy = DISCRIMINATOR
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver =  com.polaris.polaris.auth.tenant.TenantIdentifierResolver

But this gives me this error
Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.tenantContext': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton

I tried making the bean optional but it crashes as soon as I access it. also resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier is ran multiple times as soon as the application boots for some reason (which is probably the point at which the scope request tenantContext bean is unavailable). What is it used for and why can't I skip it? How can I realize the plan laid out above?

You have edited from each tenant having its own "set of tables" to its own "sections of the tables".  It's unclear to me what a section of a table is, so please clarify.  But know that if the edit invalidates the answer you had already received then it is inappropriate.

I fixed it now.

I rolled back to the original, which asks a very different question from what the edited version does.  We do not accept edits that pull the rug out from under existing answers like that.  If you find that you asked a different question than you intended to do, then you are welcome to ask a new question.

You have said two mostly-conflicting things:

"every company using the software has their own sets of tables", and
"I would like to separate the data using a TenantID Column".

JPA does not provide for any concrete entity class to be mapped to different tables in the same persistence unit.  Thus, your main alternatives would be:

Use entity inheritance with the table-per-subclass strategy for substantially all your entities, giving each tenant its own collection of entity subclasses.
This does not scale well, and it probably incurs a performance penalty. Maybe it could work for you if you don't anticipate many tenants, but that's a mess I would not be eager to create for myself.
OR

Use a different persistence unit, with all its own tables, for each tenant.
The easiest way to do this would probably be to stand up a separate instance of the whole application for each tenant.  They can share the same DB if you like.  You can of course provide a common front end to handle sign in and redirection to the correct application instance.  And inasmuch as you want to isolate tenants from each other, doing it with distinct application instances gives you even better isolation than just giving each tenant its own tables.  And perhaps use a separate VM or container for each instance to reduce hardware requirements and improve isolation even more.



your right that was badely formulated ill rephrase it. But running different spring instances for each tenant (which may number in the hundreds) seems like a nightmare of ram consumption

@user2741831, yes, one way or another, tenant isolation will consume resources.  Nothing is free, but isolation such as you're looking for is comparatively costly.

@user2741831, if you need to support hundreds of tenants then the inheritance option isn't viable.  I would probably be looking for a cloud-based approach.  Possibly cloud + several containers in each server.

I retyped. I just want one application that uses one database and one set of tables. The tables should just be discriminated by tenantId so they can't cross contaminate
